# Logarithmic speed walks on trees

Tags: co.combinatorics, random-walks

Let $T$ be the infinite $3$-regular tree, equipped with the shortest path metric $d_T$. An **infinite walk** on $T$ is a map $f:\mathbb{N}\to T$ such that $d_T(f(a),f(a+1))\leq 1$ for all $a$.

An infinite walk $f$ has **logarithmic speed** if there is a constant $C$ such that
$$
 d_T(f(a),f(b))\leq C(1+\ln(1+|a-b|))
$$
for all $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$. (Note that this prevents depth-first searches, as they typically have linear speed on large subsets.)

Is there an infinite walk $f$ with logarithmic speed which only meets each vertex a bounded number of times, i.e.
$$
 \max_{v\in V(T)} |f^{-1}(v)| <+\infty?
$$
If not, what can one say about the growth of the function
$$
 g(R) = \max_{v\in V(T)} |f^{-1}(v)\cap \{0,\ldots,R-1\}|?
$$